# display summary based on user choices without saving in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before submitting it, I would like to display in a *modal*(already created) summarizing their choices without saving yet to the database. I found some sources in net but it won't work for me.

so here's my html:

```
     <div id="step-11"> //first choice for the user
    <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="wedding"   onchange="total()" /> Wedding 
    <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="birthday" onchange="total()" />  Birthday
    <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="cake_theme" value="dedication" onchange="total()" /> Dedication
    </div>

     <div id="step-22"> //2nd choice
Other Flavor : <select name="color" id="color_display" onchange="total()" /><option value="red">red</option>
       <option value="pink">pink</option>
       <option value="blue">blue</option> </select> </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#reviewchoices" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" onclick="showReviewOrder()" value="submit" > Submit </a> //trigger to display the data.
```

for clarification the onchange=**"total()"** , it's where I put the amount of these choices, which is working good for me (located in separate file).

for my js (It's in the same page of html)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function showReviewOrder(){
        var review = document.getElementById("step-11").value; // I've tried calling the first Div 'step-11' it shows "undefined"
        reviewchoices.innerHTML= review; //reviewchoices is the id of my Modal
    }
</script>
```

it displays like this:
[image]

If I changed it into `var review = document.getElementById("theme1").value;` it display Wedding but how about the other radio buttons?
Should I make another Div ?

for my modal: ( i won't include all the modal codes, getting straight to the point)

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="reviewchoices" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<span id = "display_review"> </span> //where I'll display the user's choices
</div>
```

Hope you could help me out. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Within the div you need to find out the radio button selected and get that value

Comment: Let us know what helped and consider accepting answer if any of them helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code of showReviewOrder to this

```
function showReviewOrder(){
  var review = document.getElementById("step-11");
  var selOption=review.querySelector('input[name=cake_theme]:checked').value;
  var reviewchoices=document.getElementById("reviewchoices");
   reviewchoices.innerHTML= selOption; 

}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {

}

function total() {}

function showReviewOrder() {
  var review = document.getElementById("step-11");
  var selOption = review.querySelector('input[name=cake_theme]:checked').value;
  var reviewchoices = document.getElementById("reviewchoices");

  reviewchoices.innerHTML = selOption;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="step-11">
  <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="wedding" onchange="total()" />Wedding
  <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="birthday" onchange="total()" />Birthday
  <input type="radio" id="theme3" name="cake_theme" value="dedication" onchange="total()" />Dedication
</div>
<div id="step-22">
  Other Flavor :
  <select name="color" id="color_display" onchange="total()" />
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="pink">pink</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#reviewchoices" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" onclick="showReviewOrder()" value="submit"> Submit </a> 
<div id="reviewchoices" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria->
  <span id="display_review"> </span> /
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you! Just as I need a button to trigger to display it. Do this also applies to other steps, like I'll just change their ID in the JS?  And the  showReviewOrder, I'll just put it in the same file in html.

Comment: I tried following every steps, it won't display and I've found this in my console. - Uncaught ReferenceError: showReviewOrder is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Comment: try to bind this event at javascript end

Comment: hello, I tried adding this without changing below in the JS you gave **$( "#reviewchoices" ).bind( "click", function showReviewOrder()**  . The modal shows up fine right now, but the data isn't (the cake_theme) .

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  $('#display_review').empty()
   var userdata = $(this).serializeArray();
        jQuery.each( userdata, function( i, field ) {
  $( "#display_review" ).append( field.name + " " + field.value + "<br> " );
});
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="1" checked /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" value="3" /> 3 <br />
 <select name="selectarray">
   <option value = "1" >1</option>
   <option value = "2" >2</option>
   <option value = "3" >3</option>
   <option value = "4" >4</option>
 </select><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<span id="display_review"> </span>
```

Comment: thanks, but I need a button(trigger) to show the choices not immediately in Radio Button. I would like to summarize all the user's choice in other div .

Comment: [See the .serializeArray docs.] (http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) .

Comment: @ScottRookie I have updated my answer with exmple that will help solve your question.